# How to handle Complex Object in the ngrx?

Tags: ngrx

[image]

Hello,

I'm working on a project in which the main part of the data has a complex structure as you can see in the above picture.

Now, the object, in reality, is much complex than that but what I showed it servers the purpose.

Because in DB they are linked together in tables relationship the first time when the website is launched, after log in, a list of projects will come together with some small details of technology and dataObjects.

I created separated action and effects files but everything is handled by a single reducer. What I mean is at the start, the list of projects will be saved on a state, than any other actions like Create a project, technology, data object, edit, delete has to perform actions over the same state "projects-state".

For example besides technologyAPIS will be another 3-4 technologies, inside each technology object will be another list of objects.

The issue here is that the reducer file is getting bigger and bigger when it handles all kinds of actions that will perform actions over the specific data from the state. It is important that the chain of Objects stay together.

My question is, is this a bad approach? it can be handled in a different way? I know I can create a reducer for each entity (project, technology, data app) but I will lose that relationship between them, where one belongs to the other?

Thank you so much for your feature response

Answer (score 0):

I've only been doing reactive/NGRX for a few months now, but from my understanding, thats defiantly a `bad approach`. It should still work, but may be a hassle to debug/maintain.

Ngrx seems to be promoting 'Normalising' data, just like the usual Relational Database concept.

You could break down your `project-state` into smaller states, with relational keys in them.

---

### Example

Projects state (not to be confused with project-state)

- id:number
- projectDescription:string
- createdBy:string
- techAPIs:number[] //where the content here is the id of the TechApi

TechApi state

- id:number
- otherInfo:any

And then when you need to access the TechApi state for a project, you retrieve it and filter/map it in a selector.

[This is a some what General Example if my explanation is not understandable.](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/ngrx-store-understanding-state-selectors)